# Tasm, unexpected end of file encountered

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Как исправить ошибку `(230) unexpected end of file encountered` ?
т.е. указывает на 230ю строчку, которая идёт за `end main`

```
;prg16_1.asm
.586P       ;разрешение инструкций Pentium
.MODEL  large
include mac.inc
;структура для описания дескрипторов сегментов
descr   STRUC
limit   dw  0
base_1  dw  0
base_2  db  0
attr    db  0
lim_atr db  0
base_3  db  0
ENDS
;макрос инициализации дескрипторов
load_descr  MACRO   des,seg_addr,seg_size
    mov des.limit,seg_size
    xor eax,eax
    mov ax,seg_addr
    shl eax,4
    mov des.base_1,ax
    rol eax,16
    mov des.base_2,al
    ENDM
atr MACRO   descr,bit1,bit2,bit3
;можно использовать условные директивы
;для проверки наличия параметров
    atr_&descr=constp or bit1 or bit2 or bit3
    ENDM
;структура для описания псевдодескриптора gdtr
point   STRUC
lim dw  0
adr dd  0
    ENDS
;атрибуты для описания дескрипторов сегментов
;постоянная часть байта AR для всех
;сегментов - биты 0, 4, 5, 6, 7
constp  equ 10010000b
;бит 1
code_r_n    equ 00010000b   ;кодовый сегмент:
            ;чтение запрещено;
code_r_y    equ 00000010b   ;кодовый сегмент:
            ;чтение разрешено
data_wm_n   equ 00000000b   ;сегмент данных:
            ;модификация запрещена
data_wm_y   equ 00000010b   ;сегмент данных:
            ;модификация разрешена;
;бит 2
code_n  equ 00000000b   ;обычный сегмент кода
code_p  equ 00000100b   ;подчиненный сегмент кода
data_   equ 00000000b   ;для сегмента данных
stack_  equ 00000000b   ;для сегмента стека
;бит 3
code_   equ 00001000b   ;сегмент кода
data_stk    equ 00000000b   ;сегмент данных или стека

stk segment stack 'stack' use16
    db  256 dup (0)
stk ends
;таблица глобальных дескрипторов
gdt_seg segment para public 'data' use16
gdt_0   descr   <0,0,0,0,0,0>   ;никогда не используется
    atr gdt_gdt_8,data_wm_y,data_,data_stk
;ниже описываем саму gdt
gdt_gdt_8   descr   <0,0,0,atr_gdt_gdt_8,0,0>
;не используем
gdt_ldt_10  descr   <0,0,0,0,0,0>
    atr gdt_ds_18,data_wm_y,data_,data_stk
;дескриптор сегмента данных
gdt_ds_18   descr   <0,0,0,atr_gdt_ds_18,0,0>
    atr gdt_vbf_20,data_wm_y,data_,data_stk
gdt_es_vbf_20   descr   <0,0,0,atr_gdt_vbf_20,0,0>  ;видеобуфер
    atr gdt_ss_28,data_wm_y,stack_,data_stk
    gdt_ss_28   descr   <0,0,0,atr_gdt_ss_28,0,0>   ;сегмент стека
    atr gdt_cs_30,code_r_y,code_n,code_
    gdt_cs_30   descr   <0,0,0,atr_gdt_cs_30,0,0>   ;сегмент кода
gdt_size=$-gdt_0-1  ;размер GDT минус 1
GDT_SEG ENDS
;данные программы
data    segment para public 'data' use16    ;сегмент данных
point_gdt   point   <gdt_size,0>
hello   db  "Вывод сообщения в защищенном режиме"
hel_size=$-hello
tonelow dw  2651    ;нижняя граница звучания 450 Гц
cnt db  0   ;счётчик для выхода из программы
temp    dw  ?   ;верхняя граница звучания
data_size=$-point_gdt-1
data    ends
code    segment byte public 'code' use16
;сегмент кода с 16-разрядным режимом адресации
assume  cs:code,ss:stk
main    proc
    mov ax,stk
    mov ss,ax
;заполняем таблицу глобальных дескрипторов
assume  ds:gdt_seg
    mov ax,gdt_seg
    mov ds,ax
    load_descr  gdt_gdt_8,GDT_SEG,gdt_size
    load_descr  gdt_ds_18,DATA,data_size
    load_descr  gdt_es_vbf_20,0b800h,3999
    load_descr  gdt_ss_28,STK,255
    load_descr  gdt_cs_30,CODE,0ffffh   ;code_size
assume  ds:data
    mov ax,data
    mov ds,ax
;загружаем gdtr
    xor eax,eax
    mov ax,gdt_seg
    shl eax,4
    mov point_gdt.adr,eax
    lgdt    point_gdt
;запрещаем прерывания
    cli
    mov al,80h
    out 70h,al
;переключаемся в защищенный режим
    mov eax,cr0
    or  al,1
    mov cr0,eax
;настраиваем регистры
    db  0eah    ;машинный код команды jmp
    dw  offset protect  ;смещение метки перехода
            ;в сегменте команд
    dw  30h ;селектор сегмента кода
            ;в таблице GDT
protect:
;загрузить селекторы для остальных дескрипторов
    mov ax,18h
    mov ds,ax
    mov ax,20h
    mov es,ax
    mov ax,28h
    mov ss,ax
;работаем в защищенном режиме:
;выводим строку в видеобуфер
    mov cx,hel_size ;длина сообщения
    mov si,offset hello ;адрес строки сообщения
    mov di,1640 ;начальный адрес видеобуфера для вывода
    mov ah,07h  ;атрибут выводимых символов
outstrr:
    mov al,[si]
    mov es:[di],ax
    inc si
    inc di
    inc di
    loop    outstrr
;запускаем сирену
go:
;заносим слово состояния 110110110b (0В6h):
;выбираем второй канал порта 43h - динамик
    mov ax,0B06h
    out 43h,ax  ;в порт 43h
    in  al,61h  ;получим значение порта 61h в al
    or  al,3    ;инициализируем динамик - подаем ток
    out 61h,al  ;в порт 61h
    mov cx,2083 ;количество шагов
musicup:
;в ax значение нижней границы частоты 1193000/2651 = 450 Гц,
;где 1193000- частота динамика
    mov ax,tonelow
    out 42h,al  ;al в порт 42h
    mov al,ah   ;обмен между al и ah
    out 42h,al  ;старший байтax (ah) в порт 42h
    add tonelow,1   ;увеличиваем частоту
    delay   1   ;задержка на 1 мкс
    mov dx,tonelow  ; текущее значение частоты в dx
    mov temp,dx ;temp - верхнее значение частоты
    loop    musicup ;повторить цикл повышения
    mov cx,2083
musicdown:
    mov ax,temp ;верхнее значение частоты в ax
    out 42h,al  ;младший байтax (al)в порт 42h
    mov al,ah   ;обмен между al и ah
    out 42h,al  ;в порт 42h уже старший байт ax (ah)
    sub temp,1  ;уменьшаем значение частоты
    delay   1   ;задержка на 1 мкс
    loop    musicdown   ;повторить цикл понижения
nosound:
    in  al,61h  ;получим значение порта 61h в al
;слово состояния - выключение динамика и таймера
    and al,0FCh
    out 61h,al  ;в порт 61h
    mov dx,2651 ;для последующих циклов
    mov tonelow,dx
;увеличиваем счётчик проходов - количество звучаний сирены
    inc cnt
    cmp cnt,5   ;5 раз
    jne go  ;если нет - идти на метку go
;формирование дескрипторов для реального режима
    assume  ds:gdt_seg
    mov ax,8h
    mov ds,ax
    mov gdt_ds_18.limit,0ffffh
    mov gdt_es_vbf_20.limit,0ffffh
    mov gdt_ss_28.limit,0ffffh
    mov gdt_cs_30.limit,0ffffh
assume  ds:data
;загрузка теневых дескрипторов
    mov ax,18h
    mov ds,ax
    mov ax,20h
    mov es,ax
    mov ax,28h
    mov ss,ax
    db  0eah
    dw  offset jump
    dw  30h
jump:
    mov eax,cr0
    and al,0feh
    mov cr0,eax
    db  0eah
    dw  offset r_mode
    dw  code
r_mode:
    mov ax,data
    mov ds,ax
    mov ax,stk
    mov ss,ax
;разрешаем прерывания
    sti
    xor al,al
    out 70h,al
;окончание работы программы (стандартно)
    mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h
main    endp
code    ends
end main
```

в файле `mac.ini` просто макросы, по типу:

```
Exit    macro
;Выход из программы.
    mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h
endm
```

**P.S.**
если отключить файл макросов, то выдаёт следующее:
**prg16_1.lst**

```
Turbo Assembler  Version 3.1        27/04/19 19:21:53       Page 1
prg161.ASM



      1                  ;prg16_1.asm
      2                  .586P       ;разрешение инструкций Pentium
**Error** prg161.ASM(2) Illegal instruction
      3 0000                 .MODEL  large
      4                  ;include        mac.inc
      5                  ;структура для описания дескрипторов сегментов
      6 *000                 descr   STRUC
      7 *000  01*(0000)          limit   dw      0
      8 *002  01*(0000)          base_1  dw      0
      9 *004  01*(00)            base_2  db      0
     10 *005  01*(00)            attr    db      0
     11 *006  01*(00)            lim_atr db      0
     12 *007  01*(00)            base_3  db      0
     13 *008                 ENDS
     14                  ;макрос инициализации дескрипторов
     15                  load_descr      MACRO   des,seg_addr,seg_size
     16                      mov     des.limit,seg_size
     17                      xor     eax,eax
     18                      mov     ax,seg_addr
     19                      shl     eax,4
     20                      mov     des.base_1,ax
     21                      rol     eax,16
     22                      mov     des.base_2,al
     23                      ENDM
     24                  atr     MACRO   descr,bit1,bit2,bit3
     25                  ;можно использовать условные директивы
     26                  ;для проверки наличия параметров
     27                      atr_&descr=constp or bit1 or bit2 or bit3
     28                      ENDM
     29                  ;структура для описания псевдодескриптора gdtr
     30 *000                 point   STRUC
     31 *000  01*(0000)          lim     dw      0
     32 *002  01*(00000000)      adr     dd      0
     33 *006                     ENDS
     34                  ;атрибуты для описания дескрипторов сегментов
     35                  ;постоянная часть байта AR для всех
     36                  ;сегментов - биты 0, 4, 5, 6, 7
     37       =0090          constp  equ     10010000b
     38                  ;бит 1
     39       =0010          code_r_n        equ     00010000b       ;кодовый сегмент:
     40                              ;чтение запрещено;
     41       =0002          code_r_y        equ     00000010b       ;кодовый сегмент:
     42                              ;чтение разрешено
     43       =0000          data_wm_n       equ     00000000b       ;сегмент данных:
     44                              ;модификация запрещена
     45       =0002          data_wm_y       equ     00000010b       ;сегмент данных:
     46                              ;модификация разрешена;
     47                  ;бит 2
     48       =0000          code_n  equ     00000000b       ;обычный сегмент кода
     49       =0004          code_p  equ     00000100b       ;подчиненный сегмент кода
     50       =0000          data_   equ     00000000b       ;для сегмента данных
     51       =0000          stack_  equ     00000000b       ;для сегмента стека
     52                  ;бит 3
     53       =0008          code_   equ     00001000b       ;сегмент кода
     54       =0000          data_stk        equ     00000000b       ;сегмент данных или стека
     55
     56 0000                 stk     segment stack 'stack' use16
Turbo Assembler  Version 3.1        27/04/19 19:21:53       Page 2
prg161.ASM



     57 0000  0100*(00)              db      256 dup (0)
     58 0100                 stk     ends
     59                  ;таблица глобальных дескрипторов
     60 0000                 gdt_seg segment para public 'data' use16
     61 0000  0000 0000 00 00 00  +  gdt_0   descr   <0,0,0,0,0,0>   ;никогда не используется
     62       00
     63                      atr     gdt_gdt_8,data_wm_y,data_,data_stk
     64                  ;ниже описываем саму gdt
     65 0008  0000 0000 00 92 00  +  gdt_gdt_8       descr   <0,0,0,atr_gdt_gdt_8,0,0>
     66       00
     67                  ;не используем
     68 0010  0000 0000 00 00 00  +  gdt_ldt_10      descr   <0,0,0,0,0,0>
     69       00
     70                      atr     gdt_ds_18,data_wm_y,data_,data_stk
     71                  ;дескриптор сегмента данных
     72 0018  0000 0000 00 92 00  +  gdt_ds_18       descr   <0,0,0,atr_gdt_ds_18,0,0>
     73       00
     74                      atr     gdt_vbf_20,data_wm_y,data_,data_stk
     75 0020  0000 0000 00 92 00  +  gdt_es_vbf_20   descr   <0,0,0,atr_gdt_vbf_20,0,0>      ;видеобуфер
     76       00
     77                      atr     gdt_ss_28,data_wm_y,stack_,data_stk
     78 0028  0000 0000 00 92 00  +      gdt_ss_28       descr   <0,0,0,atr_gdt_ss_28,0,0>       ;сегмент стека
     79       00
     80                      atr     gdt_cs_30,code_r_y,code_n,code_
     81 0030  0000 0000 00 9A 00  +      gdt_cs_30       descr   <0,0,0,atr_gdt_cs_30,0,0>       ;сегмент кода
     82       00
     83       =0037          gdt_size=$-gdt_0-1      ;размер GDT минус 1
     84 0038                 GDT_SEG ENDS
     85                  ;данные программы
     86 0000                 data    segment para public 'data' use16        ;сегмент данных
     87 0000  0037 00000000      point_gdt       point   <gdt_size,0>
     88 0006  82 EB A2 AE A4 20 E1+  hello   db      "Вывод сообщения в защищенном режиме"
     89       AE AE A1 E9 A5 AD A8+
     90       EF 20 A2 20 A7 A0 E9+
     91       A8 E9 A5 AD AD AE AC+
     92       20 E0 A5 A6 A8 AC A5
     93       =0023          hel_size=$-hello
     94 0029  0A5B           tonelow dw      2651    ;нижняя граница звучания 450 Гц
     95 002B  00             cnt     db      0       ;счётчик для выхода из программы
     96 002C  ????           temp    dw      ?       ;верхняя граница звучания
     97       =002D          data_size=$-point_gdt-1
     98 002E                 data    ends
     99 0000                 code    segment byte public 'code' use16
    100                  ;сегмент кода с 16-разрядным режимом адресации
    101                  assume  cs:code,ss:stk
    102 0000                 main    proc
    103 0000  B8 0000s               mov     ax,stk
    104 0003  8E D0              mov     ss,ax
    105                  ;заполняем таблицу глобальных дескрипторов
    106                  assume  ds:gdt_seg
    107 0005  B8 0000s               mov     ax,gdt_seg
    108 0008  8E D8              mov     ds,ax
    109                      load_descr      gdt_gdt_8,GDT_SEG,gdt_size
1   110 000A  C7 06 0008r 0037           mov     gdt_gdt_8.limit,gdt_size
1   111 0010  81 36 0000 0000            xor     eax,eax
**Error** prg161.ASM(98) LOAD_DESCR(2) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(98) LOAD_DESCR(2) Argument needs type override
Turbo Assembler  Version 3.1        27/04/19 19:21:53       Page 3
prg161.ASM



1   112 0016  B8 0000s               mov     ax,GDT_SEG
1   113 0019  D1 26 0000 D1 26    +      shl     eax,4
    114       0000 D1 26 0000 D1  +
    115       26 0000
**Error** prg161.ASM(98) LOAD_DESCR(4) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(98) LOAD_DESCR(4) Argument needs type override
1   116 0029  A3 000Ar               mov     gdt_gdt_8.base_1,ax
1   117 002C  A2 000Cr               mov     gdt_gdt_8.base_2,al
    118                      load_descr      gdt_ds_18,DATA,data_size
1   119 002F  C7 06 0018r 002D           mov     gdt_ds_18.limit,data_size
1   120 0035  81 36 0000 0000            xor     eax,eax
**Error** prg161.ASM(99) LOAD_DESCR(2) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(99) LOAD_DESCR(2) Argument needs type override
1   121 003B  B8 0000s               mov     ax,DATA
1   122 003E  D1 26 0000 D1 26    +      shl     eax,4
    123       0000 D1 26 0000 D1  +
    124       26 0000
**Error** prg161.ASM(99) LOAD_DESCR(4) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(99) LOAD_DESCR(4) Argument needs type override
1   125 004E  A3 001Ar               mov     gdt_ds_18.base_1,ax
1   126 0051  A2 001Cr               mov     gdt_ds_18.base_2,al
    127                      load_descr      gdt_es_vbf_20,0b800h,3999
1   128 0054  C7 06 0020r 0F9F           mov     gdt_es_vbf_20.limit,3999
1   129 005A  81 36 0000 0000            xor     eax,eax
**Error** prg161.ASM(100) LOAD_DESCR(2) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(100) LOAD_DESCR(2) Argument needs type override
1   130 0060  B8 B800                mov     ax,0b800h
1   131 0063  D1 26 0000 D1 26    +      shl     eax,4
    132       0000 D1 26 0000 D1  +
    133       26 0000
**Error** prg161.ASM(100) LOAD_DESCR(4) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(100) LOAD_DESCR(4) Argument needs type override
1   134 0073  A3 0022r               mov     gdt_es_vbf_20.base_1,ax
1   135 0076  A2 0024r               mov     gdt_es_vbf_20.base_2,al
    136                      load_descr      gdt_ss_28,STK,255
1   137 0079  C7 06 0028r 00FF           mov     gdt_ss_28.limit,255
1   138 007F  81 36 0000 0000            xor     eax,eax
**Error** prg161.ASM(101) LOAD_DESCR(2) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(101) LOAD_DESCR(2) Argument needs type override
1   139 0085  B8 0000s               mov     ax,STK
1   140 0088  D1 26 0000 D1 26    +      shl     eax,4
    141       0000 D1 26 0000 D1  +
    142       26 0000
**Error** prg161.ASM(101) LOAD_DESCR(4) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(101) LOAD_DESCR(4) Argument needs type override
1   143 0098  A3 002Ar               mov     gdt_ss_28.base_1,ax
1   144 009B  A2 002Cr               mov     gdt_ss_28.base_2,al
    145                      load_descr      gdt_cs_30,CODE,0ffffh   ;code_size
1   146 009E  C7 06 0030r FFFF           mov     gdt_cs_30.limit,0ffffh
1   147 00A4  81 36 0000 0000            xor     eax,eax
**Error** prg161.ASM(102) LOAD_DESCR(2) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(102) LOAD_DESCR(2) Argument needs type override
1   148 00AA  B8 0000s               mov     ax,CODE
1   149 00AD  D1 26 0000 D1 26    +      shl     eax,4
    150       0000 D1 26 0000 D1  +
    151       26 0000
**Error** prg161.ASM(102) LOAD_DESCR(4) Undefined symbol: EAX
Turbo Assembler  Version 3.1        27/04/19 19:21:53       Page 4
prg161.ASM



*Warning* prg161.ASM(102) LOAD_DESCR(4) Argument needs type override
1   152 00BD  A3 0032r               mov     gdt_cs_30.base_1,ax
1   153 00C0  A2 0034r               mov     gdt_cs_30.base_2,al
    154                  assume  ds:data
    155 00C3  B8 0000s               mov     ax,data
    156 00C6  8E D8              mov     ds,ax
    157                  ;загружаем gdtr
    158 00C8  81 36 0000 0000            xor     eax,eax
**Error** prg161.ASM(107) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(107) Argument needs type override
    159 00CE  B8 0000s               mov     ax,gdt_seg
    160 00D1  D1 26 0000 D1 26    +      shl     eax,4
    161       0000 D1 26 0000 D1  +
    162       26 0000
**Error** prg161.ASM(109) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(109) Argument needs type override
    163 00E1  8C 2E 0002r            mov     point_gdt.adr,eax
**Error** prg161.ASM(110) Undefined symbol: EAX
    164                      lgdt    point_gdt
**Error** prg161.ASM(111) Illegal instruction for currently selected processor(s)
    165                  
    166 00E5  FA                 cli
    167 00E6  B0 80              mov     al,80h
    168 00E8  E6 70              out     70h,al
    169                  ;переключаемся в защищенный режим
    170 00EA  C7 06 0000 0000            mov     eax,cr0
**Error** prg161.ASM(117) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(117) Argument needs type override
    171 00F0  0C 01              or      al,1
    172 00F2  C7 06 0000 0000            mov     cr0,eax
**Error** prg161.ASM(119) Undefined symbol: CR0
*Warning* prg161.ASM(119) Argument needs type override
    173                  ;настраиваем регистры
    174 00F8  EA                 db      0eah    ;машинный код команды jmp
    175 00F9  00FDr              dw      offset protect  ;смещение метки перехода
    176                              ;в сегменте команд
    177 00FB  0030               dw      30h     ;селектор сегмента кода
    178                              ;в таблице GDT
    179 00FD                 protect:
    180                  
    181 00FD  B8 0018                mov     ax,18h
    182 0100  8E D8              mov     ds,ax
    183 0102  B8 0020                mov     ax,20h
    184 0105  8E C0              mov     es,ax
    185 0107  B8 0028                mov     ax,28h
    186 010A  8E D0              mov     ss,ax
    187                  ;работаем в защищенном режиме:
    188                  ;выводим строку в видеобуфер
    189 010C  B9 0023                mov     cx,hel_size     ;длина сообщения
    190 010F  BE 0006r               mov     si,offset hello ;адрес строки сообщения
    191 0112  BF 0668                mov     di,1640 ;начальный адрес видеобуфера для вывода
    192 0115  B4 07              mov     ah,07h  ;атрибут выводимых символов
    193 0117                 outstrr:
    194 0117  8A 04              mov     al,[si]
    195 0119  26: 89 05              mov     es:[di],ax
    196 011C  46                 inc     si
    197 011D  47                 inc     di
Turbo Assembler  Version 3.1        27/04/19 19:21:53       Page 5
prg161.ASM



    198 011E  47                 inc     di
    199 011F  E2 F6              loop    outstrr
    200               
    201 0121                 go:
    202                  
    203                 
    204 0121  B8 0B06                mov     ax,0B06h
    205 0124  E7 43              out     43h,ax  ;в порт 43h
    206 0126  E4 61              in      al,61h  ;получим значение порта 61h в al
    207 0128  0C 03              or      al,3    ;инициализируем динамик - подаем ток
    208 012A  E6 61              out     61h,al  ;в порт 61h
    209 012C  B9 0823                mov     cx,2083 ;количество шагов
    210 012F                 musicup:
    211                  ;в ax значение нижней границы частоты 1193000/2651 = 450 Гц,
    212                  ;где 1193000- частота динамика
    213 012F  A1 0029r               mov     ax,tonelow
    214 0132  E6 42              out     42h,al  ;al в порт 42h
    215 0134  8A C4              mov     al,ah   ;обмен между al и ah
    216 0136  E6 42              out     42h,al  ;старший байтax (ah) в порт 42h
    217 0138  83 06 0029r 01             add     tonelow,1       ;увеличиваем частоту
    218                      delay   1       ;задержка на 1 мкс
**Error** prg161.ASM(165) Illegal instruction
    219 013D  8B 16 0029r            mov     dx,tonelow      ; текущее значение частоты в dx
    220 0141  89 16 002Cr            mov     temp,dx 
    221 0145  E2 E8              loop    musicup 
    222 0147  B9 0823                mov     cx,2083
    223 014A                 musicdown:
    224 014A  A1 002Cr               mov     ax,temp 
    225 014D  E6 42              out     42h,al  
    226 014F  8A C4              mov     al,ah   
    227 0151  E6 42              out     42h,al  
    228 0153  83 2E 002Cr 01             sub     temp,1  
    229                      delay   1       
**Error** prg161.ASM(176) Illegal instruction
    230 0158  E2 F0              loop    musicdown    
    231 015A                 nosound:
    232 015A  E4 61              in      al,61h  61h в al
    233                  
    234 015C  24 FC              and     al,0FCh
    235 015E  E6 61              out     61h,al  ;в порт 61h
    236 0160  BA 0A5B                mov     dx,2651 ;для последующих циклов
    237 0163  89 16 0029r            mov     tonelow,dx
    238                 
    239 0167  FE 06 002Br            inc     cnt
    240 016B  80 3E 002Br 05             cmp     cnt,5   ;5 раз
    241 0170  75 AF              jne     go      ;если нет - идти на метку go
    242                  
    243                      assume  ds:gdt_seg
    244 0172  B8 0008                mov     ax,8h
    245 0175  8E D8              mov     ds,ax
    246 0177  C7 06 0018r FFFF           mov     gdt_ds_18.limit,0ffffh
    247 017D  C7 06 0020r FFFF           mov     gdt_es_vbf_20.limit,0ffffh
    248 0183  C7 06 0028r FFFF           mov     gdt_ss_28.limit,0ffffh
    249 0189  C7 06 0030r FFFF           mov     gdt_cs_30.limit,0ffffh
    250                  assume  ds:data
    251                  
    252 018F  B8 0018                mov     ax,18h
Turbo Assembler  Version 3.1        27/04/19 19:21:53       Page 6
prg161.ASM



    253 0192  8E D8              mov     ds,ax
    254 0194  B8 0020                mov     ax,20h
    255 0197  8E C0              mov     es,ax
    256 0199  B8 0028                mov     ax,28h
    257 019C  8E D0              mov     ss,ax
    258 019E  EA                 db      0eah
    259 019F  01A3r              dw      offset jump
    260 01A1  0030               dw      30h
    261 01A3                 jump:
    262 01A3  C7 06 0000 0000            mov     eax,cr0
**Error** prg161.ASM(209) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(209) Argument needs type override
    263 01A9  24 FE              and     al,0feh
    264 01AB  C7 06 0000 0000            mov     cr0,eax
**Error** prg161.ASM(211) Undefined symbol: CR0
*Warning* prg161.ASM(211) Argument needs type override
    265 01B1  EA                 db      0eah
    266 01B2  01B6r              dw      offset r_mode
    267 01B4  0000s              dw      code
    268 01B6                 r_mode:
    269 01B6  B8 0000s               mov     ax,data
    270 01B9  8E D8              mov     ds,ax
    271 01BB  B8 0000s               mov     ax,stk
    272 01BE  8E D0              mov     ss,ax
    273                  
    274 01C0  FB                 sti
    275 01C1  32 C0              xor     al,al
    276 01C3  E6 70              out     70h,al
    277                  ;окончание работы программы (стандартно)
    278 01C5  B8 4C00                mov     ax,4c00h
    279 01C8  CD 21              int     21h
    280 01CA                 main    endp
    281 01CA                 code    ends
    282                  end     main
Turbo Assembler  Version 3.1        27/04/19 19:21:53       Page 7
Symbol Table


Symbol Name     Type   Value               Cref (defined at #)

??DATE          Text   "27/04/19"
??FILENAME      Text   "prg161  "
??TIME          Text   "19:21:53"
??VERSION       Number 030A
@32BIT          Text   0               #3
@CODE           Text   PRG161_TEXT         #3  #3
@CODESIZE       Text   1               #3
@CPU            Text   0101H
@CURSEG         Text   CODE            #56  #60  #86  #99
@DATA           Text   DGROUP              #3
@DATASIZE       Text   1               #3
@FILENAME       Text   PRG161
@INTERFACE      Text   00H             #3
@MODEL          Text   5               #3
@STACK          Text   DGROUP              #3
@WORDSIZE       Text   2               #56  #60  #86  #99
ATR_GDT_CS_30       Number 009A            #81  81
ATR_GDT_DS_18       Number 0092            #71  72
ATR_GDT_GDT_8       Number 0092            #64  65
ATR_GDT_SS_28       Number 0092            #78  78
ATR_GDT_VBF_20      Number 0092            #75  75
CNT         Byte   DATA:002B           #95  239  240
CODE_           Number 0008            #53  81
CODE_N          Number 0000            #48  81
CODE_P          Number 0004            #49
CODE_R_N        Number 0010            #39
CODE_R_Y        Number 0002            #41  81
CONSTP          Number 0090            #37  64  71  75  78  81
DATA_           Number 0000            #50  64  71  75
DATA_SIZE       Number 002D            #97  119
DATA_STK        Number 0000            #54  64  71  75  78
DATA_WM_N       Number 0000            #43
DATA_WM_Y       Number 0002            #45  64  71  75  78
GDT_0           Struct GDT_SEG:0000 DESCR      #61  83
GDT_CS_30       Struct GDT_SEG:0030 DESCR      #81  146  152  153  249
GDT_DS_18       Struct GDT_SEG:0018 DESCR      #72  119  125  126  246
GDT_ES_VBF_20       Struct GDT_SEG:0020 DESCR      #75  128  134  135  247
GDT_GDT_8       Struct GDT_SEG:0008 DESCR      #65  110  116  117
GDT_LDT_10      Struct GDT_SEG:0010 DESCR      #68
GDT_SIZE        Number 0037            #83  87  110
GDT_SS_28       Struct GDT_SEG:0028 DESCR      #78  137  143  144  248
GO          Near   CODE:0121           #201  241
HELLO           Byte   DATA:0006           #88  93  190
HEL_SIZE        Number 0023            #93  189
JUMP            Near   CODE:01A3           259  #261
MAIN            Far    CODE:0000           #102  282
MUSICDOWN       Near   CODE:014A           #223  230
MUSICUP         Near   CODE:012F           #210  221
NOSOUND         Near   CODE:015A           #231
OUTSTRR         Near   CODE:0117           #193  199
POINT_GDT       Struct DATA:0000 POINT         #87  97  163
PROTECT         Near   CODE:00FD           175  #179
R_MODE          Near   CODE:01B6           266  #268
STACK_          Number 0000            #51  78
Turbo Assembler  Version 3.1        27/04/19 19:21:53       Page 8
Symbol Table


TEMP            Word   DATA:002C           #96  220  224  228
TONELOW         Word   DATA:0029           #94  213  217  219  237

Macro Name                         Cref (defined at #)

ATR                            #24  63  70  74  77  80
LOAD_DESCR                         #15  109  118  127  136  145

Structure Name      Type  Offset               Cref (defined at #)

DESCR                              #6  61  65  68  72  75  78  81
 LIMIT          Word   0000
 BASE_1         Word   0002
 BASE_2         Byte   0004
 ATTR           Byte   0005
 LIM_ATR        Byte   0006
 BASE_3         Byte   0007
POINT                              #30  87
 LIM            Word   0000
 ADR            Dword  0002

Groups & Segments   Bit Size Align  Combine Class      Cref (defined at #)

CODE            16  01CA Byte   Public  CODE       #99  101  148  267
DATA            16  002E Para   Public  DATA       #86  121  154  155  250  269
DGROUP          Group                  #3  3
  _DATA         16  0000 Word   Public  DATA       #3
GDT_SEG         16  0038 Para   Public  DATA       #60  106  107  112  159  243
PRG161_TEXT     16  0000 Word   Public  CODE       #3  3
STK         16  0100 Para   Stack   STACK      #56  101  103  139  271
Turbo Assembler  Version 3.1        27/04/19 19:21:53       Page 9
Error Summary

**Error** prg161.ASM(2) Illegal instruction
**Error** prg161.ASM(98) LOAD_DESCR(2) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(98) LOAD_DESCR(2) Argument needs type override
**Error** prg161.ASM(98) LOAD_DESCR(4) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(98) LOAD_DESCR(4) Argument needs type override
**Error** prg161.ASM(98) LOAD_DESCR(6) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(98) LOAD_DESCR(6) Argument needs type override
**Error** prg161.ASM(99) LOAD_DESCR(2) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(99) LOAD_DESCR(2) Argument needs type override
**Error** prg161.ASM(99) LOAD_DESCR(4) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(99) LOAD_DESCR(4) Argument needs type override
**Error** prg161.ASM(99) LOAD_DESCR(6) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(99) LOAD_DESCR(6) Argument needs type override
**Error** prg161.ASM(100) LOAD_DESCR(2) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(100) LOAD_DESCR(2) Argument needs type override
**Error** prg161.ASM(100) LOAD_DESCR(4) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(100) LOAD_DESCR(4) Argument needs type override
**Error** prg161.ASM(100) LOAD_DESCR(6) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(100) LOAD_DESCR(6) Argument needs type override
**Error** prg161.ASM(101) LOAD_DESCR(2) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(101) LOAD_DESCR(2) Argument needs type override
**Error** prg161.ASM(101) LOAD_DESCR(4) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(101) LOAD_DESCR(4) Argument needs type override
**Error** prg161.ASM(101) LOAD_DESCR(6) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(101) LOAD_DESCR(6) Argument needs type override
**Error** prg161.ASM(102) LOAD_DESCR(2) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(102) LOAD_DESCR(2) Argument needs type override
**Error** prg161.ASM(102) LOAD_DESCR(4) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(102) LOAD_DESCR(4) Argument needs type override
**Error** prg161.ASM(102) LOAD_DESCR(6) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(102) LOAD_DESCR(6) Argument needs type override
**Error** prg161.ASM(107) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(107) Argument needs type override
**Error** prg161.ASM(109) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(109) Argument needs type override
**Error** prg161.ASM(110) Undefined symbol: EAX
**Error** prg161.ASM(111) Illegal instruction for currently selected processor(s)
**Error** prg161.ASM(117) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(117) Argument needs type override
**Error** prg161.ASM(119) Undefined symbol: CR0
*Warning* prg161.ASM(119) Argument needs type override
**Error** prg161.ASM(165) Illegal instruction
**Error** prg161.ASM(176) Illegal instruction
**Error** prg161.ASM(209) Undefined symbol: EAX
*Warning* prg161.ASM(209) Argument needs type override
**Error** prg161.ASM(211) Undefined symbol: CR0
*Warning* prg161.ASM(211) Argument needs type override
```

**mac.ini**

```
;mac.inc
OutStr  macro   str
    push    ax
    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,str
    int 21h
    pop ax
endm
GetChar macro
    push    ax
    mov ah,01h
    int 21h
    pop ax
endm
OutChar macro
    push    ax
    mov ah,02h
    int 21h
    pop ax
endm
clear_r macro   rg
    xor rg,rg
    endm
conv_16_2   macro
    sub dl,30h
    cmp dl,9h
    jle $+5
    sub dl,7h
    endm
GetStr  macro   buf,max_len
    push    es
    push    dx
    push    cx
    xor cx,cx
    mov buf,max_len
    mov ah,0ah
    lea dx,buf
    int 21h
    mov al,buf+1
    mov cl,al
    push    ds
    push    es
    lea si,buf+2
    lea di,buf
rep movsb
    pop cx
    pop dx
    pop es
GetStr  endm
init_ds macro
    mov ax,data
    mov ds,ax
    xor ax,ax
    endm
delay   macro   time
    local   ext,iter    
    push    cx
    mov cx,time
ext:    push    cx
    mov cx,5000 ;это значение можно поменять, исходя из
iter:   loop    iter
    pop cx
    loop    ext
    pop cx
    ENDM
Exit    macro
;Выход из программы.
    mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h
endm
```

Comment: просто там макросы или нет - проблема в `mac.inc`, без него все собирается.

Comment: @extrn, добавил в вопрос, посмотрите плиз

Comment: пустую строку в конец добавляли?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, и добавлял и удалял, ошибки не пропадали

Comment: возможно старая версия ассемблера. Моя тоже не понимает `.686`, но `.586P` переваривает. для некоторых инструкций в этой программе он необходим